# Linux kernel update

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, embedded, u-boot, arch-arm

I'm trying to update the kernel version from 3.14 to 4.0.9 of Debian distribution.
For boot I'm using U-Boot, and my microcontroller is imx6 (ARM architecture).

I have the sources for the 4.0.9 kernel and for u-boot.

For my understanding, there is 5 stages to these procedure:

1. u-boot – build & compile
2. u-boot – burn to SD card
3. Kernel – build & compile
4. kernel – burn to SD card
5. boot

At the end, the process doesn't work.
I'm not familiar enough with this subject to start debug and find the problems.

My question is:

Is there a way to know if i did the first/second/third/forth/fifth stage correct and if it's works?

My main problem is:

The kernel that loaded is 3.14. The boot is work but the kernel that loaded is version 3.14, but it loaded without ethernet and other drivers. I think this is the default kernel. *If I don't interrupt the U-boot, nothing is loaded. I followed this tutorial:

http://forum.solid-run.com/linux-on-cubox-i-and-hummingboard-f8/my-boot-on-hummingboard-t3259.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on “doesn’t work”?

Comment: Do you get any error message? Can you get any sort of output from the boot process? How do you program the new kernel? (Where is it read from?) It is likely that you can do just steps 3–5 if you are upgrading the kernel and the microcontroller already has uBoot and the old kernel there.

Comment: Hello Jeff and njsg, thank for the fast reply!

The main problem: The kernel that loaded is 3.14.

The boot is work but the kernel that loaded is version 3.14, but it loaded without ethernet and other drivers. I think this is the default kernel. 

*If I don't interrupt the U-boot, nothing is loaded.

I followed this tutorial:

http://forum.solid-run.com/linux-on-cubox-i-and-hummingboard-f8/my-boot-on-hummingboard-t3259.html